# How to get the id of max count group in hive?

Tags: group-by, hive, max, hiveql

I have a table like this:

```
id , m_id , group_id
 1 ,  a   ,    0 
 1 ,  b   ,    0 
 1 ,  c   ,    1 
 1 ,  d   ,    1 
 2 ,  e   ,    0 
 2 ,  f   ,    0 
 2 ,  g   ,    0
 2 ,  h   ,    1 
 2 ,  i   ,    1
```

For each `id`, I would like to get the `m_id` which they belong to the group that has max number of `m_id`. If there is a tie, I will just take a random group of `m_id`. Hence the expected output will be like:

```
id , m_id 
 1 ,  a    
 1 ,  b    
 2 ,  e    
 2 ,  f    
 2 ,  g
```

Notice: the number from `group_id` is only an indicator of group identification under each `id`. i.e. `group_id =` 0 does not not mean the same thing between `id=1`, and `id=2`.

My original idea is to get the `max(group_id) group by (id,m_id)`, and return the `id,m_id` which has the `max(group_id`). However, this approach wont help on the tie situation (`id = 2` cases).

Really hope someone can help me on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() and  partition the group by id to get the max grouping.Then self join to get the max grouping for each id,group_id

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  id integer , m_id char(1) , group_id integer
);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (1,'a',0);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (1,'b',0);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (1,'c',1);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (1,'d',1);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (2,'e',0);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (2,'f',0);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (2,'g',0);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (2,'h',1);
INSERT INTO test (id,m_id,group_id) VALUES (2,'i',1);

select b.id,b.group_id,b.m_id
from (
         select id,group_id,row_number() over(partition by id order by id,group_id,count(*) desc) as r_no
         from test
         group by id,group_id
     ) a
join test b on b.id=a.id and b.group_id=a.group_id
where a.r_no=1
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` with aggregation to do this.

```
select t1.id,t1.group_id,t1.m_id
from (select id,group_id,row_number() over(partition by id order by count(*) desc) as rnum
      from tbl
      group by id,group_id
     ) t
join tbl t1 on t1.id=t.id and t1.group_id=t.group_id
where t.rnum=1
```